# Solution of linear (Over-determined) algebraic equations

Tags: c++, matlab, maple

I have a set of linear algebraic equations, **Ax=By**. Where **A** is matrix of 36x20 and **x** is a vector of 20x1, **B** is 36x13 and **y** is 13x1. **Rank(A)=20**. Because system is overdetermined, so least squares solution is possible, i,e; **x = (A^TA)^-1A^TBy**. I want the solution so that the residual error e = Ax-By should be minimized. I was using **Maple** to take the transpose and inverse of the matrices but taking inverse of such a big matrix takes much longer time and RAM. I even spend the whole day to take the matrix inverse but due to shortage of RAM memory it was interrupted. This is very slow and I guess not achievable with Maple.

Could anybody suggest any solution of way to do so in C++ or any other way of solving equations rather than taking inverses and transposes.

Formation of matrices,

```
    [ 1 0 0 ...0]
    [ 0 1 0 ...0]
    [ 0 0 1 ...0]    [LinearVelocity_x]
    [ 0 0 0 ...1]    [LinearVelocity_y]
    [ . . . ....], x=[LinearVelocity_z] 
A = [ . . . ....]    [RotationalVelocity_ROLL]
    [ . . . ....]    [RotationalVelocity_PITCH]    
    [ 1 0 0 ...0]    [RotationalVelocity_YAW]
    [ 0 1 0 ...0]
    [ 0 0 1 ...0]
    [ 0 0 0 ...1]
```

x is basically position(x,y,z) and orientation(Roll, Pitch and Yaw) vector.
However B is not a matrix of fixed `ones` and `zeros`. B is a matrix with elements of `sin`, `cos` of angles which are real time sensors data not a fixed data. In maple B is almost a matrix of variables and fixed elements, you can say a `dense sparse` matrix. Meanwhile, y is a vector of all the sensors or encoders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is floating-point then Maple should get this very quickly. If `A`, `B`, and `y` all have only numeric entries then try,

```
ans := LinearAlgebra:-LeastSquares( evalf(A), evalf(B.y) );
```

or, if you want the solution which itself has minimal 2-norm,

```
ans := LinearAlgebra:-LeastSquares( evalf(A), evalf(B.y), 'optimize'=true );
```

My guess is that your data is purely rational or integer, and that you may not realize that using this will cause Maple to try and find an exact rational answer. Or you might have some unknown symbolic quantity in the data (...though that could make the goal of computing minimal residual problematic). Such purely exact data, whether rational or symbolic, is a potential memory hogging nightmare and likely not at all what you really want in you are considering C++ as an alternative scheme. That is why I wrapped with calls to `evalf`, to cast the data to floats.

With purely float data, 36x20 least squares is a tiny problem and Maple should be able to do it in just a fraction of a second.

You should let the `LinearAlgebra:-LeastSquares` routine do the lifting, and not try and form or use normal equations or for Matrix inversions yourself. Use the `method=SVD` option if you want a robust approach. Let it deal with the numerical difficulties.

Comment: I have edited my question now with more detailed formulation of matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimal 2-norm"? residual error?

Comment: If your Matrix B contains symbols which do not yet have numeric values then your whole approach is wrong. You should not try and find the general symbolic solution (involving inverses of symbolic Matrices) which you might hope to evaluate later on when you have actual numeric data from the sensors. Even with a sparse problem the symbolic solution will contain enormously long symbolic expressions. Instead write a procedure which accepts actual numeric data (from sensors, eventually obtained) and then computes the LS solution numerically (on demand).

Comment: So, what do you reccomend? Eigen? or something else? Actually I am new with c++ so please guide how should I proceed